# Deactivating swap error on shutdown

Tags: swap

I randomly get deactivating Swap error on shutdown.My swap partition is on an ATA disk in an usb enclosure and connected to the laptop via usb.Its always mounted on boot and there is no problem with that.
Can anyone help me in answering if thats the cause? And if its indeed, any workaround?
Thanks for reading this.
Some specs from hdparm of the disk.

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       TOSHIBA MK8034GSX                       
    Serial Number:      47JHFKA7S
    Firmware Revision:  AH301H  
Standards:
    Supported: 7 6 5 4 
    Likely used: 7
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   156301488
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:   156301488
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:       76319 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:       80026 MBytes (80 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
```

Comment: Does the external USB disk have its own AC power supply, or does it just draw power from the USB port that it's plugged in to? What version Ubuntu? Any reason that you couldn't run with a /swapfile?

Comment: Hi George,It draws power from USB port,no separate power supply.I got an SSD with the root partition on it and on this ATA i got swap and home.I dont want to put the swap on SSD as i read it will eventually decrease the lifespan with extensive swapping (each write wears a memory cell etc.) .The laptop is 12 years old.I have put in 4gb ram with xfce so that it leaves room for me to get my work done maxing out on ssd and 4gb ram.A lot of swapping goes on.

Comment: Modern SSDs don't have a problem with swap. Either add an AC power supply to your external disk, or move swap to your SSD. With only 4G RAM, it will swap. Create/update your swap to 4G minimum. (I'm not George... he only edited your question for better readability).

Comment: My apologies heynnema.Thanks.I created a swap partition of 8G on the ssd.There was 10G of unallocated space i left out for headroom on the ssd.updated fstab to permanently swap on that.Not using the one on ATA anymore to swap.Will monitor for a few days.Hopefully the error will go away.Appreciate ur help.

Comment: Do I need to update the new UUID of the swap anyplace else other than fstab or do something more ? I can see swapon -s swapping to the new swap partition but I feel the xwindows desktop rendering is a little slower than before. Boot time is fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Did that,update#1 steps.Still that rendering is a bit choppy.Thanks nonetheless since it was needed.Yesterday night i put MS office on  Playonlinux.I did both changes a nearly the sametime.Do you think the pol+office got anything to do with it?I cant see anything on xsession startup

Comment: We weren't aiming to fix rendering issues, we were working on swap at shutdown problems. What video card make/model do you have? What version driver? Why PoL and MS Office? What's wrong with LibreOffice? How much of my Update #1 did you need to do... probably not all of it I'd guess. Show me `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: swap    sw              0       0
UUID=266d3e92-41ea-459c-ba98-3845391cb524  none            swap    sw              0       0 Swappiness is 30, free -h               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2.9G        631M        1.4G        128M        864M        1.9G
Swap:          9.4G          0B        9.4G

Comment: Is assume that you mean `UUID=266d3e92-41ea-459c-ba98-3845391cb524 none swap sw 0 0`. What about `free -h`. After I see that, I'll update my answer again.

Comment: You have 4G RAM?

Comment: See Update #2 in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern SSDs don't have a problem with swap. Either add an AC power supply to your external disk, or move swap to your SSD. With only 4G RAM, it will swap. Create/update your swap to 4G minimum.

Verify proper swap operation by using the `free -h` or `swapon` command.

**Update #1:**

Creating a `/swapfile` on the SSD will require four things...

- properly create `/swapfile` or swap partition
- edit `/etc/fstab`, change any existing swap lines with current UUID, or for `/swapfile` to:

  `/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0`
- edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` if it exists

  - `sudo -H gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`
  - `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)`
- edit `/etc/default/grub` and check for `resume=` kernel parameters

  - `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`
  - `sudo update-grub`

**Update #2:**

Video rendering problems. With only 4G RAM, **setting vm.swappiness=30 is absolutely wrong**.

You really need more RAM. Always add RAM in matched pairs, so that the system can take advantage of memory interleaving. So, if you've got one 4G DIMM now, add a matching 4G DIMM. Or, replace the 4G DIMM with two 8G DIMMs.

We'll try and reset your vm.swappiness to a more reasonable value for your current memory size...

Set vm.swappiness=80 (based on 4G RAM and 10G SWAP), this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=80`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=80` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`